# Understanding the different pieces in native android crash logs

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, tombstone, android-native-library

I have an android crash log and need help understanding some things

1) What does r0-r9, sl, fp, ip stand for

```
   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xe9403ff8
    r0 e7b982cc  r1 e95011b0  r2 e7a7a370  r3 e95011dc
    r4 e95011b0  r5 e7b982ec  r6 e7b982cc  r7 e99f67c0
    r8 00000001  r9 00000001  sl e9a6c988  fp e7c032d8
    ip 00000001  sp e9404008  lr e9fe3bc1  pc e9fe3a84  cpsr 000f0030
```

2) How to utilize the memory near r0, r1, sl etc. Sometimes there are some readable characters which can be utilized to interpret. So wanted to understand how to associate that with the actual crash
3)

Comment: They are register names http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731128950.htm

Comment: Thanks @AlanBirtles ... I thought so these are registers names .. but at the time of crash what will be the contents of the same? I sometimes see readable chars next to memory near r0 is that the code it was executing when crashed?

Comment: You need to use a debugger to see what the registers are being used for at any particular time in your code, it will vary from line to line (or even within a line) and depends on how your compiler decided how to use the registers